# how can i play piece of sound sample by web sound API?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have an "asd.wav" sample with total duration 3 secs and play it:

```
let source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = buffer; // recieved buffer of asd.wav
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
source.start(0);
```

It plays perfectly from 0.00 to 3.00 second, but how i can play this sample only from 1.00 to 2.00 second?

Comment: please share the whole code. Where do you get `buffer` from?

Comment: @sid-m as example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGrxvy . cant attach "asd.wav" (need a pro acc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to explicitly requesting the resource to be played and slicing out a portion of it, you can also leverage an `audio` element. Per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Specifying_playback_range), by appending `#t=[starttime][,endtime]` to the URL, you can specify the portion of interest.

From there, it's a trivial matter of creating a source from the media element and playing it, rather than doing it all from scratch.

As with an AJAX request, you're still subject to Cross-Origin restrictions.

Here's an example - just substitute the URL with one on the same domain, one referring to a resource with a CORS header, or one that uses your own server as a proxy to a compatible resource that doesn't come with the CORS header.

As you can see, the code for this method along with its accompanying HTML requires far less code than the AJAX approach does. You can also create and load `audio` elements dynamically as shown in the button click handler.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}
///////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    //loadAndPlayPortion("3 seconds.wav", 0.0, 1.0);
    playAudioElement( byId('myAudioElem') );
};

function onBtnClicked(evt)
{
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.onloadeddata = function(){ playAudioElement(this); };
    audio.src = '3 seconds.wav#t=2,3';  // could build this URL from user input
}


function playAudioElement(audioElem)
{
    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElem);
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    audioElem.play();
}


function loadAndPlayPortion(soundUrl, startTimeSecs, endTimeSecs)
{
    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("GET", soundUrl, true);
    ajax.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    ajax.onload = onFileLoaded;
    ajax.send();

    function onFileLoaded()
    {
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(this.response, onDataDecoded);
    }

    function onDataDecoded(sampleBuffer)
    {
        let source = audioCtx.createBufferSource(), numChannels=sampleBuffer.numberOfChannels,
            sampleRate = sampleBuffer.sampleRate,
            nRequiredSamples = (endTimeSecs-startTimeSecs)*sampleRate,
            newBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer( numChannels, nRequiredSamples, sampleRate);
        for (var curChannel=0; curChannel<numChannels; curChannel++)
        {
            var channelData = sampleBuffer.getChannelData(curChannel);
            channelData = channelData.slice(startTimeSecs*sampleRate, endTimeSecs*sampleRate);
            newBuffer.copyToChannel(channelData, curChannel, 0);
        }
        source.buffer = newBuffer;              // chosen portion of received buffer of sound-file
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.start(0);
    }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick='onBtnClicked()'>Create Audio element</button>
    <audio id='myAudioElem' src='3 seconds.wav#t=1,2'></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. May be it can be done in a simpler way, but this what I could come up with.

```
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();

var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
getSound.open("GET", "./asd.wav", true);
getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";
getSound.onload = function() {
  audioCtx.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
    let start_time = 1, end_time = 2, sample_rate = buffer.sampleRate,
        channel_number = 0; // assuming a mono (one channel) audio
    let source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    let data = buffer.getChannelData(channel_number);
    data = data.slice(start_time * sample_rate, end_time * sample_rate)
    let new_buffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1 /*number of channels =1*/ , data.length, sample_rate);
    new_buffer.copyToChannel(data, 0);
    source.buffer = new_buffer
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start(0);
  });
};

getSound.send();
```

In case of multi channel audio, you will need to repeat the steps to copy data to each channel.

Comment: seems awesome! i try it at home (after 4 hours), thank you!